# 2 numbers are chosen at random from set $\{1,2,3..5n\}$ (without replacement). Find the probability that $n_1^4-n_2^4$ is divisible by 5

Tags: probability

All the numbers can be written in the form of $5k,5k+1,5k+2,5k+3,5k+4$

Also the given expression can be written as
$$(n_1-n_2)(n_1+n_2)(n_1^2 + n_2^2)$$

**Case 1**

Let $n_1-n_2$ be a multiple of 5

Which implies that both numbers have to be of the from $5k$, ie. $n$ possible numbers

**Case 2**

Let $n_1+n_2$ be a multiple of 5

So $(n_1,n_2)$ can be $(5k,5k), (5k+1, 5k+4), (5k+4, 5k+1), (5k+2,5k+3), (5k+3, 5k+2)$

With $n$ cases for each ordered pair

**Case 3**

Let $n_1^2 + n_2^2$ be a multiple of 5

So here cases can be 5k and 5k only (IMO)

The cases with $(5k,5k)$ are repeated 3 times, so count that as one case only

So
$$P=\frac {\binom n2 + 2\times \binom n2 +2\times \binom n2}{\binom {5n}{2}}$$

But that doesn’t match with the given answer $\frac{17n-5}{5(5n-1)}$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Because of Fermat, $n_1^4-n_2^4$ is not divisible by $5$ exactly  when either $n_1$ or $n_2$ is divisible by $5$, but not both.

Comment: $n_1^2 + n_2^2$ can be divisible by $5$ if $n_1 = 5k_1+1$ and $n_2 = 5k_2 + 2$, or $5k_1 + 4$ and $5k_2 + 3$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since $5$ is a prime number
$$
n^4=1\pmod 5
$$
due to [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) for all $n\ne 0\pmod5$.

Thus the probability in question is this of the event that the two chosen numbers either both divisible or indivisible by 5:
$$
p=\frac45\cdot\frac{4n-1}{5n-1}+\frac15\cdot\frac{n-1}{5n-1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Idea:  separate into two sets $$S_1=\{5,10,15,..,5n\}\\S_2=\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,...,5n-1\}$$now note that dividing by $5$ for each number (to the power of 4)has two remainders
$$a=5k+0\to r_1=\underbrace{a^4}_{mod 5}=0\\
a=5k+1\to r_2=\underbrace{a^4}_{mod 5}=1^4=1\\
a=5k+2\to r_3=\underbrace{a^4}_{mod 5}=2^4=16(mod \ 5)=1\\
a=5k+3\to r_4=\underbrace{a^4}_{mod 5}=3^4=81(mod \ 5)=1\\
a=5k+4\to r_5=\underbrace{a^4}_{mod 5}=2^4=256(mod \ 5)=1\\$$ so $n_1^4,n_2^4$ can choose from $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $5|n_1^4-n_2^4$ now
$$P=\frac { \binom n2 + \binom {4n}2}{\binom {5n}{2}}$$